# Retrieve count against each entry in one table from some other table in a single view in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a **User** table and a **Community** table. A user can join multiple communities and a community can have multiple users. So I have a relation table named **CommunityUser** table. **CommunityUser** table have **UserID** and **CommunityID** that defines which user registered in which community.
What I want to show on my **search view** is
[This is somewhat same as Facebook Groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrR6Z.jpg)

I am displaying Community **Logo**, **Title** and **details** from Community Table with a @foreach loop but I also want to add a count of each communityID from a **CommuntyUser** Table.
Here is my Community **Model Class**

```
public class Community
{
   [Key]
    public int CommunityID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CommunityName { get; set; }

    public string CommunityAbout { get; set; }

    public string CommunityLogo { get; set; }

    public int PrivacyID { get; set; }

    //I am trying to get members count using this
    public virtual  IEnumerable<CommunityUser> CommunityUsers { get; set; }


}
```

Here is my **controller** function where I am applying this

```
    public ActionResult ShowSearchResults(string SearchQuery)
    {


        var communitySearch = from m in db.Communities
                              select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchQuery))
        {
            communitySearch = communitySearch.Where(s => s.CommunityName.Contains(SearchQuery));
        }



        return View(communitySearch);
    }
```

Here is my **view** class. I have removed extra code and mentioned where i need count from CommunityUser Table.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{


    <div class="row">


        <div class="col-md-4">

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CommunityName)
            <br>
            @ViewBag.Count

   <!--Need to count of members in that community-->
   <!--means How many times that communityID appeared in CommunityUser table-->

        <br>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CommunityAbout)

    </div>

</div>
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick fix I can think of is 
Create a new model which should have following properties and I will name is as CommunityWithUserCount

- Community
- UserCount

After that change your existing code to follwoing

```
var communityQuery = db.Communities.Include("CommunityUsers").AsQueriable();
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchQuery))
    {
        communityQuery = communityQuery.Where(s => s.CommunityName.Contains(SearchQuery)).AsQueriable();
    }

var yourCustomObject = communityQuery.Select(elem => new CommunityWithUserCount()
{
 Community = elem,
 Count = elem.CommunityUser.Count()
}).ToList();
```

I hope this works for you. I have to not compiled/tested this code. It just an idea I think will solve your problem.

Comment: And how can I access this count list in my view class?

Comment: Now instead of passing old model just pass this custom model in this you will have community user count.